# Как запускать звук без задержёк в pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pygame

Когда я запускаю `pygame.miser.music.play()`, то звук происходит с задержкой.

Как запускать звук без задержек?

Comment: Код в студию, экстрасенсы в отпуске, нужно больше инфы, там может быть из-за чего угодно. Дело в том, что вы скорее всего вызываете каждый раз звук заново, следовательно, задержка происходит из-за того, что звуку нужно загрузиться и потом только воспроизвестись, нужно инициализировать в начале все это дело, а потом только пользоваться `play`, хотя в `pygame`.довольно плохо это сделано там не кеша ничего нет, по этому возможно придется рыть глубже. НО опять-же, гадать на кофейной гуще нет смысла.

Comment: уже нашла магические цифры и все стало хорошо)

Comment: Ну хоть ответом-то поделитесь, мало ли у кого возникнет такая же проблема

Comment: Нашла на просторах интернета и уже бросила затею рпг на питоне и решала перейти на C#, так что у меня все уже давно удалено